# Proving equivalence of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to prove the equivalence of two equations, and have reduced them to:

$f'''+ff''+\beta(1-f'^2)=0$          Eq(1)

and

$f'''+\frac{1}{2}(m+1)ff''+m(1-f'^2)=0$          Eq(2)

with the relationship between $m$ and $\beta$ of

$\beta=\frac{2m}{1+m}$       Eq(3)

When I substitute (3) into (1) I get

$f'''+ff''+\frac{2m}{1+m}-(\frac{2m}{1+m})f'^2$

but cannot see where to go from here.